# java.lang.illegal state exception

Tags: java, jsp

```
if (request.getParameter("print_type") != null) {
    String print_type = request.getParameter("print_type").toString();

    if (print_type.contains("1"))//Preprinted page
    {
        session.removeAttribute("default_selected_opd_ticket");
        session.setAttribute("default_selected_opd_ticket", "1");

        if (session.getAttribute("opdTicket_preprinted") != null) {
            printpg = session.getAttribute("opdTicket_preprinted").toString();
        } else if (print_type.contains("3"))//Preprinted page
        {
            session.removeAttribute("default_selected_opd_ticket");
            session.setAttribute("default_selected_opd_ticket", "3");
            printpg = "../opdreport/antenatal_report.jsp";

        }

    } else {  //for blank page
        session.removeAttribute("default_selected_opd_ticket");
        session.setAttribute("default_selected_opd_ticket", "2");

        if (session.getAttribute("opdTicket_blank") != null) {
            printpg = session.getAttribute("opdTicket_blank").toString();
        } else {
            printpg = "../opdreport/opdTicket_blank.jsp";
        }
    }

    //  printpg = "../opdreport/opdTicket_blank.jsp";//this is a jsp
    request.getSession().setAttribute("backpage", backpg);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("printpage", printpg);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("regNo", registration.getRegistrationno());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("pID", registration.getPatientid());

    registration = null;
    if (request.getParameter("SelectedOption") != null) {
        String strSelectedOption = request.getParameter("SelectedOption").toString();

        if (strSelectedOption.equals("withoutNk")) {
            response.sendRedirect("../opdreport/printframe.jsp");
            return;
        } else if (strSelectedOption.equals("withNK")) {
            response.sendRedirect("../opdregistration/Nk1Details.jsp");
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Above a part of the code is given. Here I am not able to redirect to the mentioned jsp page.

All the datas are getting saved without redirecting to the page giving a illegal state exception error. Here I am using three radio buttons with value 1,2,3 respectively.

The user will select the radio button according to the requirement & according to that it will redirect to the respective page.

Comment: could you please paste the exception stacktrace as well?

Comment: Need to fix your code formatting (there's a preview of the post below the edit box, no excuse for posting something that doesn't look right; get it correct *then* post). Right now the question is pretty unreadable.

Comment: The exception message text tells you exactly what's wrong. What did it say? Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

In all probability, you've already written to the response stream before doing the `sendRedirect()`. An `IllegalStateException` is thrown if you try to redirect after flushing to the output stream or writing a cookie or a header etc.